# rails show optgroup based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

So I'm trying to do something similar to the Railscast Dynamic Select Menus #88 video. I have a Category model which has_many entrees and has_many sides. So I have 3 models instead of 2. I'm trying to use the Category of the selected entree to then filter the sides. Another difference compared to the Railscast is I have many forms not just one.

This code works the first time I select something, but the sides are empty if I change my selection to anything else afterwards. Thank you in advance for your help and let me know if I need to add any additional code/info!

EDIT: Here's a link to see it action https://jsfiddle.net/ky0pkavd/

Here's my form:

```
<%@restaurants.each do |restaurant| %>
    <h3><%=restaurant.name%></h3>
    <%= form_for [@customer,@meal] do |f| %>
       <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:food_item, restaurant.categories, :entrees, :name, :id, :name) %>
       <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:side, restaurant.categories, :sides, :name, :id, :side_item) %>
       <%= f.submit "Submit meal", class: "btn btn-primary", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to submit this meal?' } %>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(".new_meal #meal_food_item").on('change', function() {
var restaurant = $(this).parent().parent().eq(0)
        var sides = $(restaurant).find("#meal_side").html()
        var category = $(restaurant).find("#meal_food_item :selected").parent().attr('label')
        var options = $(sides).filter("optgroup[label="+category+"]").html()
         if (typeof options !== 'undefined') {
           $(restaurant).find("#meal_side").html(options)
         }
         else {
           $(restaurant).find("#meal_side").empty()
         }
      });
```

Comment: can't repeat ID's in a page...change those id's to classes. Beyond that it's not clear what your issues are. A demo in a javascript sandbox like jsfiddle.net would help

Comment: @charlietfl sorry for the delay https://jsfiddle.net/ky0pkavd/ I think it's because of line 8 in javascript. Instead of replacing the html maybe I should just hide the rest of the optgroups?

Comment: can't hide options ...not supported cross browser. Notably IE doesn't recognize events or display. best is to cache a set and rebuild the inner html from cache if you want some removed and be able to replace them again

Comment: Any guidance on that @charlietfl? I'm a new developer so I really don't know anything regarding cacheing

Comment: can copy the elements using jQuery clone() and store in variable(cache). Then always filter another clone of that stored cache

Comment: @charlietfl I'm struggling to make that work. Any chance you can show me a working example? The issue I'm having essentially is I don't know how to reset the html when a second change occurs. I vaguely understand clone(), but I'm losing the clone I think after the first change.

Comment: store the clone right away on page load...outside the even handler. Then each time you need it you copy that clone again using clone() ... so original stays in variable

Comment: @charlietfl I'd really benefit from an example. Unfortunately haven't been able to make this work